# jQuery delay not working after three seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

After 3 seconds... the alert prompted does not show up. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(function() {
    $("#test").live("click",function() { 
         $("#test2").delay(3000, function({
            alert('Hello!');
         }) );
        });
    });
```

Comment: I hate to say it, but RTFD and you'll see that `.delay()` simply does not work like that: http://api.jquery.com/delay

Comment: @weka: Even if your use of `.delay()` was correct, your syntax is broken. This part isn't valid: `function({ alert('Hello!'); })`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.delay()` doesn't accept a callback. Use `setTimeout`.

```
$(function() {
    $("#test").live("click",function() { 
         setTimeout(function() { alert('Hello!'); }, 3000);
    });
});
```

I could show you how you could *technically* make it work with `.delay()`, but given your example, it just wouldn't be appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Nowhere is it documented that `delay()` accepts parameters in that form.

```
$(function() {
    $("#test").live("click", function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert('Hello!');
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

Indeed the [`delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) documentation has a **bold** statement;

> **The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.**

Comment: +1 for including the docs link, and the most relevant portion.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the jQuery delay is used to delay the next chained function call. You should be using [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) instead

```
$("#test").live("click",function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        alert('Hello!');
    }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.delay()` only works with jQuery effects methods that use the animation queue like `fadeIn()`, etc...  And, `.delay()` doesn't accept a callback.

You will have to use `setTimeout()` like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#test").live("click",function() { 
         setTimeout(function() {
            alert('Hello!');
         }, 3000);
    });
});
```